# New browser window with epecific status

Tags: javascript, html, browser, cross-browser, popupwindow

I want to open a new browser window without menu bar, tool bar or address bar and with a specific size (say 300 x 600 px), positioned at top left.

How can I do this in a cross browser manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.open ("http://www.javascript-coder.com","mywindow","menubar=0,resizable=0,width=350,height=250");
```

or with specific position

```
window.open('yourpage','mywin','left=0,top=0,width=600,height=300,toolbar=0,resizable=0,menubar=0');
```

references:

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/openinga.htm

http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) and [`window.moveTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.moveTo).

Note though that most browsers will force an address bar upon the popup window for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.open("your URL","win",'toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=1,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,width=785,height=600');
```

window.open() method has support in all major browsers
  [Refer this page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)